# Question about powers of a number, modulo a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have a feeling this one was already asked, or is so well-known that it hasn't needed asking yet, but I can't find an answer.

I was looking into divisibility of $10^{2n} + 1$, after finding that $10^{2n + 1} + 1$ is always divisible by $11$. After looking into divisibility of powers of numbers by primes generally, I came across a result I thought was interesting, but I can't prove it or find anything else out about it.

It appears to me that:

> If $2p + 1$ is an odd prime, and $q$ is coprime to $2p + 1$, then $q^p$ is congruent to either $1$ or $-1$ mod $2p + 1$.

- Is this in fact the case?
- If so, when is the power congruent to $-1$ and when is it congruent to $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. It follows from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).
2. It is $1$ exactly when $q$ is a square mod $p$. This is [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Comment: Thanks! So, it's definitely really basic, but kind of interesting :-)

Comment: I'm missing something though. I can see that a^2p is congruent to 1, and therefore that a^p is its own inverse. But how do I get from there to see that a^p is 1 or -1? What am I missing?

Comment: @MattGutting, $2p+1$ is a prime that divides $a^{2p}-1=(a^p+1)(a^p-1)$.

Comment: duh. Thanks :-\